# Visa refusal due to misrepresentation

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, visa-bans, deception

I travelled to the US with my mum when I was 6 we overstayed and returned to my native country when I was 13. I recently applied for a tourist visa with my husband and concealed information about my overstay in the US in the past. I told the consular officer that I have not visited the US. I figured this information wouldn't be important because I was a minor when I was there and did not want to complicate it as I was not previously told reasons of our departure
He denied my application based on 212 (a) (6)(I)  misinterpretation. My question is, is this a permanent ban?  What steps can I take to rectify this situation and reapply? And will it affect my husband and kids?  My husband visits the US often.

Comment: The vote to close this question in favor of [Expatriates.SE] is incorrect.  This question is not about long-term immigration, but rather about an application for a tourist visa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86266/discussion-between-honorary-world-citizen-and-greatone).

Comment: @greatone Please don't answer questions in the comment section, as it states when you try to write one. All that long comment thread bickering would have been avoided if you did, and the policy is in place because of that.

Comment: How would a small child understand whether she had overstayed?  The blanket exemption for minors is there for a reason, not only because they have no choice, but also *because the minor child couldn't possibly be expected to know anything about immigration law*.

Comment: I have deleted the comments which are now to be found in the chat room.

Comment: @Harper A minor is not responsible for their overstay for exactly the reasons they state, but a full-grown adult is responsible for lying to immigration officials when applying for a visa. It's inconceivable that the asker wasn't aware, aged 13, that they were living in the USA, which means that they knew that the statement that they'd never visited the USA was false.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if that was the question.  If the question was "have you been in the US *illegally* in the past" different deal.

Comment: @Harper Please read the question carefully before commenting. The asker says "I told the consular officer that I have not visited the US." Regardless of what question prompted that statement, the statement was a lie.

Comment: @Harper have you considered reading the questions carefully before commenting instead?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. They are all so insightful. I shouldn't have lied,that's where my mistake was. I have consulted a lawyer and have done some research, I have come across waivers and filing in motions to vacate. The motion to vacate the charge has a quicker processing time and is more reasonable I just hope legal fees won't be too expensive during this process

Answer (score 20):

I think you meant 212(a)(6)(C)(i), at which concerns misrepresentation (not misinterpretation), codified at [8 USC 1182(a)(6)(C)(i)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_6_C_i):

> Any alien who, by fraud or willfully misrepresenting a material fact, seeks to procure (or has sought to procure or has procured) a visa, other documentation, or admission into the United States or other benefit provided under this chapter is inadmissible.

The inadmissibility is not limited in time, but there is a waiver available.  The application fee is high (currently $930), and the fee is lost if the application is unsuccessful.

You are unlikely to overcome this without professional legal help.  You should try to find an immigration lawyer who has experience helping clients with misrepresentation bans.

Comment: I don't think there is a fee to apply for an INA 212(d)(3)(A) nonimmigrant waiver.

Answer (score 3):

> And will it affect my husband and kids? My husband visits the US
>   often.

Nobody can answer definitively if it will. It should not. The [policy manual](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8.html) does not state nor imply anywhere a person becomes inadmissible or should their visa be denied because a spouse committed an immigration offense. Although married you are two different adults and your applications will be evaluated separately.

Unfortunately however consular officers are human beings with wide latitude to approve or deny nonimmigrant visa applications without appeal and  your misrepresentation **could** prejudice him against your husband.

Comment: That is a low quality answer without any substance. It has two sentences both of which contain should or could.

Comment: Is there a source that you have relied on your answer: nobody knows? No answer would have been better than having should and could without any basis.

Comment: Does the manual call for refusing a persons nonimmigrant application solely because a spouse committed an immigration offense?

Comment: It's not my answer, it's yours. You bring the proofs. Simply saying could or should is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: @greatone I don't think it's necessary to offer authoritative support for the assertion that consular officers are human beings or that their decisions may be biased by factors they're not supposed to consider.  I would be surprised, though, if evidence concerning the spouse were really supposed to be excluded from evaluation of immigrant intent.  I don't see the relevant section of the manual, however.

Comment: I would tend to agree, the use of weasel words (could) and generic arguments (they're only human) should maybe call for extra strong support of the fundamental claims.  *See what I did there?*